# Post-build step in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Eclipse SDK 3.5.1, CDT.
I have the following workspace tree:

```
Bin (just directory)
--Debug
--Release
Client (project)
--Debug
--Release
```

In the Client project, Debug configuration, I fill Post-Build step:

```
cp Debug/Client ../Bin/Debug/
```

I want to copy output executable to Bin/Debug directory.
Building the project, I have this error message:
make[1]:[post-bulld] Error 1 (ignored) line 0

What is wrong?
Also, can I use some variables, like Workspace directory, current configuration etc. in Post-Build step? Where can I find these variables and how to use them?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever find out how to use build variables in the Post-Build command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found solution: current directory is Debug, and not project directory, the command should be:

```
cp Client ../../Bin/Debug/
```